# Why are some properties of my style object being ignored in ng-style?

Tags: css, angularjs

I have this style object in my controller:

```
p: {
  'font-family': 'Lucida Grande\', \'Lucida Sans Unicode\', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif',
  'margin': '0'
}
```

Only 'margin' is honored (in Chrome Dev Tools, 'margin' is found in the 'Styles' list in the 'Elements' section).   Anyone see an issue with the font-family I've specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
'font-family': '\'Lucida Grande\', \'Lucida Sans Unicode\', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif',
```

It may be because you need an opening apostrophe `'` before Lucida Grande, the one currently there would not serve that purpose.